# Updating El Capitan to High Seirra will take 18 hours

Tags: macos, high-sierra, upgrade, software-update

I'm on El Capitan and trying to update to High Seirra. It downloaded the stub file and run the application. I waited for one hour till it says 17 hours remaining. Is there a way to speed up the update process?

Comment: Do you have much data in `/usr/local/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None whatsoever.

Leave it alone, it will get there.

If it's claiming such astronomical time remaining, it's based on 'how fast it went so far vs how long it thought it should have taken'. That's a variable dependant on many things - HD vs SSD, space remaining on drive etc.

Also, your download speed will have an effect - maybe significant if your connection is slow or intermittent. [I've never had a download be slow or fail, but I would assume the installer is capable of handling a failed download gracefully].

It will recalculate periodically as it works, so you might find it will drop to something more sensible as it progresses.

One thing to watch out for… when it gets to "1 minute remaining" don't run out of patience at that point. It is really saying "I've done everything I can measure & these final tweaks should only take a minute." If it has a lot of files to look at, it may take hours. It can't tell you at that point.

Comment: The main issue I have with it is that you can't pause and resume. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: None whatsoever. It's got a lot of data to move around & has to change the partition format too. Don't run out of patience or you'll lose it all & probably have to recover from Time Machine.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I perhaps ought to add that to the answer. I'd actually forgotten what it's like to have a slow connection; how easy it is to get used to something that "just works".

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin. Just one more question? Is it to much risk to upgrade without backing up?

Comment: These days it's too much risk to not have a backup, period. Whether you lose last night's homework, your business plan to convince Newcastle to buy your coal, or just pictures of your departed dog, backups are vital in this day & age.

Comment: Haha I meant is there a great chance that the upgrade will fail?

Comment: If you leave it, it will eventually complete or fail gracefully. If you switch it off it won't.